# Content URI TO Android Room (SQLite conversion)

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I am given a task where I need to change the activity. The Activity uses Cursor Loaders, Cursor and Content Uri.

```
Uri tempUri = some function call; That calls // BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_ROUTES).build();
```

> This will give

> content://com.companyname.android/route/routeID/stops/sRcH

My task involves converting this URI to an SQL Query. How can I do that? I have a little idea about cursor since I have worked mostly in Room DB. How can I convert this into a query? I am unable to convert this into a SQL Query because I am not able to figure out what is the database in this, what is the table name or subtable name. Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I need to convert this URI to an SQL query that I can write in Android Room.

Comment: "I am not able to figure out what is the database in this, what is the table name or subtable name" -- we cannot answer that. Somebody in your organization is going to have to tell you what the different pieces of that `Uri` mean and how they tie into your database schema. Nobody outside of your organization will know that.

Comment: Can You give some tip on how can I see this stuff? Or Figure it out please? Like can you give an example how will you convert your uri to an sql query? Any Example of this type will help. Thanks

Comment: Like you can make any arbitrary content:// uri and convert it into SQL query.

Comment: "Like you can make any arbitrary content:// uri and convert it into SQL query" -- no, no more than you can take an arbitrary URL like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71896603/content-uri-to-android-room-sqlite-conversion` and convert it into a SQL query. Your `Uri` was created by a programmer. You need to talk to that programmer and ask that programmer what the different pieces of that `Uri` mean and how they tie into your database schema.